# pip install rauth fails : syntax error

Tags: python, pip

I just installed Python 3.3 and then I tried to install rauth by issuing the command:

pip install rauth

and I get this error:

```
Downloading/unpacking rauth
Running setup.py egg_info for package rauth
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
    File "c:\users\pipul\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-pipul\rauth\setup.py", l
    ine 4, in <module>
    from rauth import __version__
    File ".\rauth\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .service import OAuth1Service, OAuth2Service, OflyService
    File ".\rauth\service.py", line 23
    except KeyError, e:  # pragma: no cover
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

File "c:\users\pipul\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-pipul\rauth\setup.py", line 4, in    <module>

from rauth import __version__

File ".\rauth\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>

from .service import OAuth1Service, OAuth2Service, OflyService

File ".\rauth\service.py", line 23

except KeyError, e:  # pragma: no cover

               ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\pipul\appd
```

ata\local\temp\pip-build-pipul\rauth
    Storing complete log in C:\Users\pipul\pip\pip.log

```
## Heading ##c:\Python33\Scripts>
```

Similarly installing oauth2 also fails. But installing selenium succeeds.

Now what could be the thing that is causing this failure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That package doesn't support Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many packages, rauth currently does not support Python 3.  However, it looks like there is a branch where they are working on it.  See [here](https://github.com/litl/rauth/issues/82).

In general, you may have more luck installing packages if you use Python 2.7.

Comment: Thank you very much. But just one thing - the problem indicates some basic syntac error like except. Isn't it already part of python?

Comment: The syntax for raising exceptions in Python 3 is slightly different.  Check out this site: http://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html.  Specifically, look at the "Capturing the Currently Raised Exception" section.